# Let us know why you need access to this site after upgrade

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, upgrade

I upgraded site collection from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 but problem is users are unable to access it. They get following error message:

> Let us know why you need access to this site

I have checked that users are already there in Permissions in new site collection of SharePoint 2013 (both 2010 and 2013 are part of same AD)

Do I need to somehow upgrade users also?

Comment: is the web app in the 2010 classic and in 2013 a claims based? looks like  migrate user issue...

Comment: Yes 2010 is classic and 2013 is claims based. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's PowerShell script to fix this issue.

You need to replace domain\user with the actual domain and user name. Need to do this for all users one by one or may be you can improve it by using a loop to do all at once.

Also note you need to use appropriate number for content database. In the example below since I only have one content database hence i am using $wa.ContentDatabases[0]

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://myserver
$acc = 'domain\user'
$arguments = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPMigrateUserParameters
$arguments.AddDatabaseToMigrate($wa.ContentDatabases[0])
$wa.MigrateUsersToClaims($acc, $true, $arguments)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of ways to do this.

- either convert the Web Application in SP 2010 from Classic to Claims then upgrade to 2013.
- or create a Classic Web Application in 2013 then upgrade the content database to 2013 then convert the web application.

  - Create Web Application as Classic mode is only possible via PowerShell

> ```
> New-SPWebApplication -name "ClassicAuthApp" -Port 100 -ApplicationPool 
> "ClassicAuthAppPool" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount 
> "<domainname>\<user>")
> ```

- Now After this attach the Content Database to web app
- Now Run the Conversion command like this

  Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity  -To Claims 
  -RetainPermissions [ -Force]

Please read this TechNet for all options. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx

Comment: I used MigrateUsersToClaims method to fix the issue.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spadministrationwebapplication.migrateuserstoclaims.aspx